# Chaining functions that return arrays of promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have something similar to the following, and want to know if there is a 'chainy' way to do it, or if I'm off the mark and this represents a smell.  Thanks!

```
  var promises = Q.all(returns_a_promise()).then(returns_array_of_promises);
  var more_promises = Q.all(promises).then(returns_another_array_of_promises);
  var even_more_promises = Q.all(more_promises).then(yet_another_array_o_promises);

  Q.all(even_more_promises).then(function () {
    logger.info("yea we done");
  });
```

Ideally something like:

```
  Q.all(returns_a_promise())
   .then(returns_array_of_promises)
   .all(returns_another_array_of_promises)
   .all(yet_another_array_o_promises)
   .all(function () {
    logger.info("yea we done");
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Q.all(returns_a_promise())
   .then(returns_array_of_promises).all()
   .then(returns_another_array_of_promises).all()
   .then(yet_another_array_o_promises).all()
   .then(function () {
    logger.info("yea we done");
  });
```

Answer (score 6):

Just return `Q.all` from the functions directly, like this

```
Q.all(returns_a_promise())
    .then(function() {
        return Q.all(array_of_promises);
    })
    .then(function() {
        return Q.all(array_of_promises);
    })
    .then(function() {
        return Q.all(array_of_promises);
    })
    .done(function() {
        logger.info("yea we done");
    });
```

For example,

```
Q.all([Q(1), Q(2)])
    .spread(function(value1, value2) {
        return Q.all([Q(value1 * 10), Q(value2 * 10)]);
    })
    .spread(function(value1, value2) {
        return Q.all([Q(value1 * 100), Q(value2 * 100)]);
    })
    .spread(function(value1, value2) {
        return Q.all([Q(value1 * 1000), Q(value2 * 1000)]);
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log(arguments[0]);
    })
```

would print

```
[ 1000000, 2000000 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your promises are structured, you can also use `reduce` to simplify things:

```
var promiseGenerators = [
  returns_array_of_promises,
  returns_another_array_of_promises,
  yet_another_array_o_promises
]

promiseGenerators.reduce(function (chain, item) {
  return chain.then(function () {
    // invoke item, which returns the promise array
    return Q.all(item())
  });
}, returns_a_promise())
.done(function () {
  logger.info("yea we done");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent:

```
return Q.all([a, b]);
```

-

```
return Q.fcall(function () {
    return [a, b];
})
.all();
```

https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-middle